# Console log actual variables from MobX store, not Proxy obejcts

Tags: javascript, mobx

Variables fetched from MobX store become `Proxy` objects in the console.

How can we log the actual variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using .toJS()?

https://mobx.js.org/api.html#tojs

Answer (score 7):

Im using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Mobx [docs](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#converting-observables-back-to-vanilla-javascript-collections).

Example:

```
console.log({ ...StoreName.objectYouWantToLog });
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested objects, you can also use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(storeName))`